# How to add paragraphs in an item of a list in TinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4, rich-text-editor

I want to add some paragraphs in the same item of a list. Like:

> 1. Text text text
>
>    Text in a new paragraph
> 2. Text text text

Is there anyway to do this in TinyMCE?

Comment: Just select the text within the list item and then select "Paragraph" from the Toolbar (or if Menubar is visible then Format > Blocks > Paragraph).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when typing in a list select `paragraph` from the top left corner. and then press `ctrl+enter` or `ctrl+return` for next line.

So this will be.
for example, I am typing in a list:

> 1. this is the first item of the list.
> 2. this is the second item of the list `(select paragraph now)` and this `(press ctrl+return)` may contain more than one line
> 3. this is the third line

so this will render:

> 1. this is the first item of the list.
> 2. this is the second item of the list and this
>
>    may contain more than one line.
> 3. this is the third line

[image: see POC]

Comment: Some old versions (possibly customized) of TinyMCE may require `ctrl + shift + enter` so try this if you notice that `ctrl + enter` adds only a new line in the same block

Answer (score 3):

I found a simple way to create paragraphs in lists.

1. User <kbd>Shift + enter</kbd> to create a line break in the list item.
2. Select the text and select `Paragraph`. TinyMCE converts the `<br>` into paragraphs.

[image]

Comment: `<br>` is not the same as a new paragraph (`<p>`). It might look similar visually, but the markdown is different.

Answer (score 2):

1. Click OL from the editor.
2. Add item one, Add item two, etc.
3. Go back to the item you want to have a paragraph and hit enter creating a new li.
4. Tab twice.
5. Backspace the tabs (twice), this will remove the new li.
6. Go back to the li you wanting the paragraph again and hit enter creating another li.
7. Tab twice.
8. Backspace twice.

Oddly doing it twice in WYSIWYG will do it.

Here are those steps in action:

[image: 1]

The example above will put an ol/ul within the parent li producing someting like:

```
<ol>
<li>OneHad to do it twice.
<ol>
<li style="list-style-type: none;">&nbsp;</li>
</ol>
</li>
<li>TwoAgain, had to do it twice.
<ol>
<li style="list-style-type: none;">&nbsp;</li>
</ol>
</li>
<li>ThreeOdd, but it works :)
<ol>
<li style="list-style-type: none;">&nbsp;</li>
</ol>
</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Mmm, for that kind of solution it is easier to press "Shift + Enter" and make a line break with `<br />`